# What am I doing wrong with pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I've a function that reads N lines from a text file and save them into a first array (`array_slave`). After that, I'm trying to save the last for element of this array into another array (`char *last_4_samples[128]`). First question: is it right? Am I doing it right?

```
char *retrieve_last_4_samples(char slave[], char file_path[]){

        FILE *fp;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
    
        fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
    
        if (fp == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        char *array_slave[128];
        int i = 0;
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
        {
            if (strstr(line, slave) != NULL)
            {
                array_slave[i] = malloc(sizeof(*line)*len);
                strcpy(array_slave[i], line);
                i++;
            }
        }
    
        int number_of_samples = array_length(array_slave);
    
        char *last_4_samples[4];
        
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            *(last_4_samples + i) = *(array_slave + i); 
        }
    
        for(int i=0;i<number_of_samples;i++)
            free(array_slave[i]);
            
    
        return last_4_samples;
    
    }
```

Now, in the main function, I'm trying to assign the pointer `last_4_samples` to another pointer, so that I can use it into the main.

```
char *ptr[128];
ptr = retrieve_last_4_samples(SLAVE_1,FILE_PATH);

main.c:50:9: error: assignment to expression with array type
   50 |     ptr = retrieve_last_4_samples(SLAVE_1,FILE_PATH);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ptr` is an array of 128 pointers to `char`. You cannot assign anything to an array in C. Also `last_4_samples` in that function is an array of 4 pointers. `return last_4_samples` returns the address of that local array. You mustn't return the address of a local variable. It's lifetime will be over when you are back in the caller's function

Comment: *"On success, `getline()` and `getdelim()` return the number of characters read, including the delimiter character, but **not including the terminating null byte** (`'\0'`)"*. So you need to allocate one more byte of memory.

Comment: `malloc((sizeof(*line) + 1) * len)`.  The size of a C string is one plus the length, because there is a terminating null byte which doesn't count as part of the length.

Comment: @Kaz but `malloc(1 + sizeof(*line) * len)` You have added 1 to the size of *each element*.

Comment: This line should also generate a diagnostic: `return last_4_samples`. The expression's pointer type is not compatible with the function's return type.

Comment: @WeatherVane Neither! It should be `sizeof(*line) + sizeof(*line) * len`. What I wanted was `sizeof (*line) * (1 + len)`.   Of course `sizeof(*line)` is 1, but it's good to write something that will work if the type changes to something else like `wchar_t`.  If we've gone to the trouble to use `sizeof(*line)` instead of 1, it should be consistent in the entire expression.

Comment: you cannot return `last_4_samples`. It will be invalid after function is done.

Comment: The function or macro `array_length` seems problematic.  I think what you want there is `i`

Comment: This is the legacy of C (the language C++ is based on). Change to `std::array<char*, 4> last_4_samples;` and `std::array<char*, 4> retrieve_last_4_samples(blah blah)` and you'll have no problem with returning the array, but your program still has other bugs in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two mistakes:

1. `free(array_slave[i]);` destroys memory for all elements of the array, including last 4 samples. So, whatever is in the `last_4_samples` is destroyed as well, because you used pointers in assignments: `*(last_4_samples + i) = *(array_slave + i);`

As a result the last `last_4_samples` becomes invalid *even* before return.

2. you are returning `last_4_samples` which is declared as a local array on the function stack. This will become invalid in any case after return from the function.

To follow your scheme you need to

1. duplicate your string, e.g., `*(last_4_samples + i) = strdup(*(array_slave + i))`
2. avoid declaring arrays for the return:
   `char **last_4_samples = malloc(sizeof(char*), 4);`

now you can return the value of the last_4_samples pointer.
Of course, you will need to free it later, but in two steps:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   free(returned_samples[5]);
free(returned_samples);
```

Comment: "free(array_slave[i]); destroys memory for all elements of the array" overstates.  `free()` may or may not "destroy" memory. It is simply undefined behavior to access after freeing.  Might work, might not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica for all practical purposes freed memory must not be used by the program.

Comment: "destroyed" implies some specified action on the free'd memory.  C does not specify any action - just UB to attempt to use.  A classic counter case involves security leaks where  free'd memory is thought to no longer contain useful/accessible info as it is "destroyed", but no such destruction certainly occurred.